# tensorflow - Why an array is different when called in metrics function?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I want to do multiclass classification (3 classes) and I would like to record recall and accuracy for each of the subclasses.

But I face a problem I do not understand.

Here is the labels for testing dataset :

input:

```
print(y_test)
```

output :

```
[[0. 1. 0.]  [0. 1. 0.]  [0. 1. 0.]  ...  [1. 0. 0.]  [0. 0. 1.]  [0.
    1. 0.]]
```

=> ok for that (first image is from 2nd subclass, second image also from 2nd subclass...)

But when I code my custom metric function, for example:

input:

```
def recall(y_test, y_pred):

    print(y_test)

    hello = 1

    return hello


model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", 
              optimizer = opt,
              metrics=[recall])
```

output :

```
Tensor("activation_2_target_21:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)
```

I really do not understand what this means.
Please, could you give me an explanation  ?

Kindly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not different, it is just in Tensor form. You can see the value of this tensor by running it through the session or turn on eager-execution (if you are not using Tensorflow 2.0). It will be same.

For turning on eager execution, use `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()`.

Comment: Hello @Abhishek Verma ! However I am using Tensorflow 2.0. So it should appear in its array form, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should. Can you this code in Jupyter notebook, so, you can see the variable. Not executing it as a file may help.